# Error in: http://../ScriptResource.axd ? This is an invalid script resource request

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

My website is in C#, ASPX 2.0
I got the below error message in my `ERRORlog.text` 
What is that? Only references I can find for "ScriptResource.axd" in my project are in `web.config` file.

Error Message: `Error in: .../ScriptResource.axd?d=diKF0HRDsUNRWo81sxPlRIsBGEHipi8D_xLxj7KNA3lzJv1KpBnul_TgkXCGAr4jLEJV5UfPZGnyoOPyakLpOmhTB9aJQm_EQQvRt7NWOlXW4G53uIgljz1gANH8ud4gEpFhb1rmrYr0vjYoVIOCkWPMSU1&t=ffffffffcf199a8b`

Error Message: `This is an invalid script resource request.`

Comment: Here are refs from web.config

1. Line 103: <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>

Comment: 2. Line 139: <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Please help me to sort out this error?